# Django - selectively query models using pk_url_kwarg

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Consider the these two models and view:

**models.py**

```
class BHA_List(models.Model):
    well = models.ForeignKey(WellInfo, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_list')
    bha_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BHA_overall(models.Model):
    bha_number = models.ForeignKey(BHA_List, 'CASCADE', related_name='bha_overall')
    drill_str_name = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    depth_in = models.CharField(max_length=111)
```

**views.py**

```
class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = BHA_overall
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'
    form_class = BHA_overall_Form
```

To my understanding, `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'` will query and return instances of `model = BHA_overall`.

Let's say that I use a different `CBV` other than `UpdateView`, and want to implement two models. So something like this:
`model = (BHA_overall, BHA_List)`. Is there any way that I force my `pk_url_kwarg = 'pk_alt'` to query and return instances only in `BHA_List`, but force my `get_object()` return objects in `BHA_overall`?? What `CBV` should I use?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can't you just follow the relationship from one to the other in the template?

Answer (score 0):

you can use just 'View' and define methods post and get.
about like this:

```
class SomeView(View):
      model = BHA_List
      template_name = 'some.html'
      def get(request, **kwargs):
          overall = BHA_overall.objects.all()
          return render(request,
                        self.template_name,
                        locals())
      def get(request, **kwargs):
          return render(request, self.template_name, {})
```